# Openstack Image- How to delete openstack image by last usage?

Tags: openstack-glance

I am writing a python script to delete openstack images based on the last access date.

But from the documentation of image object **openstack.image.v2.image.Image** I could only get **updated_at** and **created_at** dates of image and not the last accessed date.

Is there any other way by which I can get the last-access date of image?

Any help/suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried something? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Do your research and if you're having problems with your code, you're always welcome to ask a question here. Please see [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

"Last access date image" means that which running instance using the  image ?  and when  that instance was created ?